# using wiringPi2-python (non root) segmentation fault catching for GPIO

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, gpio

i'm using wiringPi2-python to switch a raspberry GPIO pin from low to high and back.
Everything works BUT right after it switches the pin's value a `Segmentation fault` is thrown and the program stops.
I need to use this approach because this seems to be the only way to access the GPIO pins without `sudo`

before starting the program i need to setup the pins to output and export them so:

```
$ echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
```

and then a bit of python shell:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wiringpi2 as pi
>>> pi.wiringPiSetupSys()
0
>>> pi.digitalWrite(17, 1)
Segmentation fault
$
```

i tried this approach, but it wasn't any better. The program still stopped.:

```
try:
        pi.digitalWrite(17, 0)
except:
        print('got an error')
print('just printing something to see if gets to end')
```

So my question is how can i catch the error properly, so i could just ignore it because the code actually works.
Ps: This is propably worth a bug report but i want to get my head around it first.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C"?

Comment: because wiringpy2-python uses C underneath. and i think try and except aren't working because of that. Not sure though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it out. i need to make another process for `digitalwrite`. In that case the newly created process stops but the rest of the program can continue working.

```
import wiringpi2 as pi
from multiprocessing import Process

def process(choice):
        if choice == "1":
                pi.digitalWrite(17, 1)
        else:
                pi.digitalWrite(17, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        pi.wiringPiSetupSys()
        choice = raw_input(">")
        p = Process(target=process, args=(choice,))
        p.start()
        p.join()

print('just printing something to see if gets to end')
```