# WiringPi gpio called by system() must use another process?

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi2, wiringpi

According to [this](http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/), I'm using the system() ([QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html)) function from inside my program to call the gpio program.

It works. But I've noticed I need to run my app two times, in fact it only works at the second time. It seems the call to gpio must be done in another process, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828758/using-wiringpi2-python-non-root-segmentation-fault-catching-for-gpio).

Should this problem be approached with [QProcess::setupChildProcess()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setupChildProcess)?

I extended QProcess overwriting setupChildProcess and then just instanciated SandboxProcess in the constructor of my app. Unfortunately, this didn't worked.

```
class SandboxProcess : public QProcess
{
 protected:
     void setupChildProcess();
};
void SandboxProcess::setupChildProcess()
{
    QString program = "/usr/local/bin/gpio";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "export" << QString::number(4) << "out";
    start(program, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `QProcess::setupChildProcess()` doesn't help because it's own process starts after the main app proccess. So the main app still fells like the export command was not executed.

At this point I see two options:

1. To make a `ManagerApp`, which call `gpio` (to do the exports) and then call (another) `MyApp` which will actually access the exported devices.
2. Use the `gpio` app directly and listen to their `stdout` via `signal/slot`, using `QProcess`.